# Validation against XSD: Get first Facet causing exception

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd

I'm validating a XML against a XSD. No problem here. But now, I want to know which Facet of my restrictions is causing an error.

For example, with the restriction :

```
<xs:simpleType name="Max35Text">
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:minLength value="1"/>
<xs:maxLength value="35"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

I want to retrieve the facet XmlSchemaMaxLengthFacet on the ValidationEventHandler if my string is longer than 35. I already know how to get the restrictions list for the concerned node but I don't know how to find wich one is causing the exception.
How can I do that ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I have edited your title. Please do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose. Also see, ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/19190/193440), where the consensus is "no, they should not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to do it by my self.
I retrieve the XmlSchemaSimpleTypeRestriction like this :

```
XmlSchemaSimpleTypeRestriction restriction;
XmlSchemaSimpleType simpleType;
switch (reader.NodeType)
{
    case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
       if (reader.SchemaInfo.SchemaElement == null) return null;
       simpleType = reader.SchemaInfo.SchemaElement.ElementSchemaType as XmlSchemaSimpleType;
       if (simpleType == null) return null;
       restriction = simpleType.Content as XmlSchemaSimpleTypeRestriction;
       break;
    case XmlNodeType.Attribute:
       if (reader.SchemaInfo.SchemaAttribute == null)
           return null;
       restriction = reader.SchemaInfo.SchemaAttribute.AttributeSchemaType.Content as XmlSchemaSimpleTypeRestriction;
           break;
    default:
       return null;
}
return restriction;
```

Next I parse each facet of them and try each of them like this :

```
XmlSchemaMaxExclusiveFacet currentFacet = facet as XmlSchemaMaxExclusiveFacet;
if (Convert.ToDecimal(strXmlValue) >= Convert.ToDecimal(currentFacet.Value))
    return "error";
```

If none of them is causing the error, I use the XmlSchemaExceptionErrorType to adapt the error message.